# sed: can't read book/ : No such file or directory

Tags: replace, sed, grep

I ran the following one line code on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

```
 grep -rl 'room' book/ | xargs sed -i 's/room/equipment/g'
```

And I got the following message

```
sed: can't read book/
book/del_entry_ajax.php: No such file or directory
```

Acutally I can run

```
grep -rl 'room' book/del_entry_ajax.php | xargs sed -i 's/room/equipment/g'
```

successfully and then run the first command again, I got

```
sed: can't read book/
: No such file or directory
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do your files have any "odd" characters in their names? Does your script (if this is in a script) have DOS line endings? If you don't care about timestamps changing (and the added work you can avoid the `grep`/`xargs` here entirely and just run `sed` over all the files. It won't make modifications to files that don't match (though it will copy and replace them anyway).

Comment: Write: `grep -rl 'room' book/ | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 sed -e 's/room/equipment/g' -i`

Comment: Thx. I finally find that there is a file named `\\` which causes this weird error.  (I do not even know how to type the backward slash as code format in stackoverflow)

Answer (score 3):

The GNU guys really messed up when they gave `grep` an option to **find** files. There is a perfectly good UNIX tool to **find** files and it has a perfectly obvious name - `find`. Try this:

```
find book -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/room/equipment/g'
```

Comment: And what about using `-exec` directly like `find ... -exec sed -i ...`?

Comment: Sure, `find` is what the OP is looking for, but I think `grep -Hnr project_folder` pretty useful. It is super convinient to step to a certain line using `vi file +line_number` after that.

Comment: I personally always avoid `-exec` because it makes trivial jobs very slightly briefer but then needs a complete rewrite or too much complexity when the job becomes slightly more interesting.

Comment: @hek2mgl I'd do `find project_folder | xargs grep -Hn` which isn't so bad.

Comment: @EdMorton You are referring to [Eric Raymond's 17 UNIX rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Eric_Raymond.E2.80.99s_17_Unix_Rules)? (In this case the *Rule of Composition* I guess?)

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for feedback! (Sorry, was in a boring meeting). I once stumpled upon that Wikipedia article and was really impressed about the worthful information and thoughts in it. I still like grep `-r`, but I definitely see the concerns about it. Probably it would be better to use `rgrep` instead of `grep -r` and define it as a bash function which internally calls `find -type f | grep PATTERN`  ..