# How to grep and replace string in multiple files in osx El Capitan

Tags: linux, macos, bash, grep, osx-elcapitan

I went through all the available answers here but none of them worked. I want to replace the word 'http:' with 'https:'. Here is what I do:

```
find . -name '*.job.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/http/https/g"
```

I get the following error:

sed: can't read s/http/https/g: No such file or directory

Also tried:

```
grep -l 'http:' * | xargs sed -i "" 's/http\:/https\:/g'
```

and got:

grep: ebay-sync: Is a directory
sed: can't read s/http:/https:/g: No such file or directory

Comment: Looks like your `sed` doesn't like the empty argument to `-i`.  Which is unusual if you are on OSX, but that's what it looks like.

Comment: As an aside, the colon has no special meaning in regular expressions, and thus does not need to be backslash-escaped.

Comment: Can't you use `find -exec` instead of piping to `xargs`?

Comment: I think I tried find -exec as well and it didn't work. I'm going to research further.

Comment: OP, as an aside, are you aware of the existence of http://apple.stackexchange.com/ (for Apple-specific questions), http://unix.stackexchange.com/ (for Unix-specific questions), and http://superuser.com/ (for power users)? You might search for an answer on one of those sites.

Comment: Thanks Shoover. I will use those from this time on. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With bash 4 (released 20th of February, 2009):

```
shopt -s globstar
sed -i '' 's/http/https/g' **/*.job.xml
```

---

From `man bash`:

> `globstar`: 
>                         If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context  will  match  all
>                         files  and  zero  or  more directories and subdirectories.  If the pattern is
>                         followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.

Comment: Same error unfortunately: shopt -s globstar THEN sed -i '' 's/http/https/g' **/*.job.xml gets me: sed: can't read s/http/https/g: No such file or directory

Comment: The OSX bash is 3.x No idea why Apple never update the basics - GRRRR!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this one worked for me the best:

find *.job.xml -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/http:/https:/g'

Credit to this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577145/sed-cant-read-book-no-such-file-or-directory)